# android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content exception in android

Tags: android, bundle

In my application i'm using customized window title. and on back pressed i'm calling oncreate method of same activity.i'm getting following exception how can i call oncreate method of same activity onbackpressed-

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

code is-

```
     private Bundle mBundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBundle=savedInstanceState;

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);  
               .
               .
               .
 }

  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onBackPressed();
    if(backFlag){
        onCreate(mBundle);
        backFlag=false;
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Answer**- I got solution for the problem. on backpressed i'm calling same activity again

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onBackPressed();
    if(backFlag){

        backFlag=false;
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want to call onCreate() manually? the code which you want to execute on back pressed, write that in seperate method and call that method. it is not a good programming to call onCreate() manually

Comment: NO need to start the Actiivty again which will maintain the activity in the backstack..You want to show the same activity for that just dont call finish() or super.onBackpressed() check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not because of the order of calling methods in  `onCreate()` ..You are getting this exception because of this line..

```
 if(backFlag){
    onCreate(mBundle);
    backFlag=false;
}else{
    finish();
}
```

when you backpressd you are agin calling onCreate() method of the activity It will try again call the `requestWindowFeature()` but all the views alreay added so its gives you a exception remove `onCreate()` from `onBackPressed()` then it will work fine.

If you dont want to close your activity onBackpressed dont call `super.onBackpressed` thats it..

Update like this..

```
 if(backFlag){
          backFlag=false;
}else{
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> requestFeature() must be called before adding content

=> Exception itself suggest you that Don't call `requestFeature()` before adding content (i.e. `setContentView()`)

Now, Issue is at this point:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

Solution:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

### Update:

One more thing, why do you need to call `onCreate()` again in `onBackKeyPressed()`?

Answer (score 1):

Move this line 
`getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);` 
above 
`setContentView(....);`

Answer (score 1):

Change your onCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mBundle=savedInstanceState;

      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);  
               .
               .
               .
 }
```